# How to show an empty row in BootstrapVue's b-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I am using a b-table from BootstrapVue. However, when the array of objects for my table is empty, i want to show the table headers + 1 empty row, without any text in the cells of the table.

On [BoostrapVue's b-table page](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#table-style-options), there is some explanation about showing something for an empty table, but i'm not following the explanation. There is also no visual of the outcome.
When using `show-empty`, it gives a simple text 'no records ...', but i don't want the text. Or maybe i want a custom text (depending on the language when using i18n).

So the html is currently:

```js
<b-table bordered :head-variant="'light'" hover :items="dogs" :fields="dogHeaders" >
</b-table>
```

And in the vue data i have:

```js
dogs: [], //because i want to mimic an empty table
dogHeaders: ['name','color','age'],
```

Can someone show me an example how to do this?

edit: i currently see only a workaround with populating my dogs array with an empty dog like so:

```js
dogs: [{name:'',color:'',age:''}],
```

But i guess there should be a better way (+ this workaround gives a row that has less height than an actual filled row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to render actual cells, you can use the `top-row` slot instead of the standard `empty` slot.

You can then conditionally render the slot using a `v-if`, based on whether the `dogs` array is empty or not.
Then render empty cells (`<td>`) inside the slot for each element in your `dogHeaders` array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() { 
    return {
      dogs: [],
      dogHeaders: ['name', 'color', 'age']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addRow() {
      this.dogs.push({
        name: 'Pence',
        color: 'Black',
        age: 53
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-btn @click="dogs = []">Reset Table</b-btn>
  <b-btn @click="addRow">Add row</b-btn>
  <hr />
  <b-table bordered head-variant="light" hover :items="dogs" :fields="dogHeaders">
    <template #top-row v-if="dogs.length === 0">
      <!-- Adding &nbsp; to the cell so that it maintains the standard cell height -->
      <td v-for="i in dogHeaders.length">&nbsp;</td>
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Only improvement suggestion i have is for using dogHeaders instead of dogHeaders.length in the v-for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `b-table` with `show-empty` attribute and `slots`. I prepared a code snippet to show this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dogs: [],
    dogHeaders: ['name', 'color', 'age'],
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <b-table bordered :head-variant="'light'" hover :items="dogs" :fields="dogHeaders" show-empty>
    <template #empty="scope">
        Empty row
    </template>
  </b-table>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost what i want. But is there no way of mimicing a real row? (in this case we have 3 columns, so a row with 3 empty cells). I'm not sure how that can be done by just using these slots

Answer (score 2):

I think the example is right there in the [docs](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#custom-empty-and-emptyfiltered-rendering-via-slots). They provide slots for exactly this use case, where you can put anything you want:

```
<b-table bordered :head-variant="'light'" hover :items="dogs" :fields="dogHeaders" show-empty>
    <template #empty="scope">
        Whatever HTML you put here will be shown when the table is empty
    </template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: i tried that, but it doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/xzbkLrta/4/

Comment: @BrotherWoodrow You're missing the `show-empty` prop to enable the `empty` slot.

Answer (score 0):

"bootstrap-vue": "2.21.1"

"vue": "2.x"

```
    const formatter = (value) => value ? value : '---'
    const tableColumns = [
        { key: 'name', formatter: value => formatter(value) },
        { key: 'color', formatter: value => formatter(value) },
        { key: 'age', formatter: value => formatter(value) },
        { key: 'sex', formatter: value => formatter(value) }
    ]
```